# Flutter - using PictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage returns blank image

Tags: flutter, android-canvas, flutter-layout, drawimage

I am trying to create a new Image from two existing images using Canvas

1. one Img from asset ("asset image")
2. one Img from network

To achieve that first problem is to draw "asset image" on Canvas using drawImage.. this is where I am facing the problem.

drawCircle is working fine, But for using drawImage as per following code, it is outputting blank image.

I am new to using Canvas and experimenting, any help appreciated..

Complete code..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:async';
//import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Image _image;
  ui.Image imagetoDraw;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _image = new Image.network(
      'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png',
    );

    getImageFromAsset();
  }

  getImageFromAsset() async {
    imagetoDraw = await load('images/loading.png');
    print('...getImageFromAsset done');
  }

  Future<ui.Image> load(String asset) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return fi.image;
  }

  _generateImage() {
    _generate().then((val) => setState(() {
          _image = val;
        }));
  }

  Future<Image> _generate() async {
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas c = new Canvas(recorder);
    var rect = new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    c.clipRect(rect);

    final paint = new Paint();
    paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
    paint.color = const Color(0xFF333333);
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final offset = new Offset(50.0, 50.0);
//    c.drawCircle(offset, 40.0, paint); 

    c.drawImage(imagetoDraw, offset, paint);

    var picture = recorder.endRecording();

    final pngBytes = await picture
        .toImage(100, 100)
        .toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    var image = Image.memory(pngBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
    return image;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _image,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _generateImage,
        tooltip: 'Generate',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you gotten any clarity on this?

Comment: Any solution? Struggling with same problem

Answer (score 0):

The image asset path seems to be the problem. I can not say that for sure, as There is no `pubspec.yaml` asset declarations here.

Let's assume that you have added assets in `pubspec.yaml` as below:

```
assets:
  - assets/images/image_01.png
  - assets/images/image_02.jpg
```

In that case, you need to specify the path of asset 'assets/images/image_01.png'. 
Means the exact path that is defined inside the `pubspec.yaml` file.

i.e. In your case, `imagetoDraw = await load('assets/images/image_01.png');`

**Tip:** You can directly use `Image.asset('assets/images/image_01.png');` to get the image from assets.

The source I have referred to: [Load Image from assets in flutter](https://fluttermaster.com/load-image-from-assets-in-flutter/)

I hope this helps.